# Softlayer Java Api to create volume using Rest API client

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been using the softlayer-api-client (.0.2.3),  by using these API client I am able to order the virutal server in IBM softlayer cloud, then able to get the VM and list those VM. sample code below

```
Guest.Service service = Guest.service(client);
```

In the guest I am setting all VM related information, then place order

```
guest = service.createObject(guest);
```

while create VM, few of the default block device (disk) getting attached to the VM instance.

Do we have similar kind of RestApiClient service to Create/delete the additional volume?

please share the API to create the volume.

Let me know in case need further clarification for the same.

Answer (score 0):

in order to add or delete volumes to the VSI you need to upgrade/downgrade your machines, this process only can be achieve using the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder method:

this is an example using RESTFUL:

```
POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

body: 
    {
        "parameters": [{
            "virtualGuests": [{
                "id": 49495232
            }],
            "prices": [{
                    "id": 2277,
                    "categories": [{
                        "categoryCode": "guest_disk1",
                        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category"
                    }],
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                },

                {
                    "id": 2270,
                    "categories": [{
                        "categoryCode": "guest_disk2",
                        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category"
                    }],
                    "complexType": "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                }
            ],
            "properties": [

                {
                    "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
                    "value": "adding disks"
                },

                {
                    "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
                    "value": "2014-08-25T9:50:00-05:00"
                }
            ],
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade"
        }]
    }
```

I do not have at hand an example using the Java but the idea is the same you need to send all of data (If you have troubles with the code in Java let me know and I will make the example in Java). Also you may be interested in this documentation about how the placeOrder method works  http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3

Comment: Thanks Nelson for your quick response.

Comment: I have already upgraded softlayer with latest SDK 0.2.3, you mean there is no REST API client support to Add/Delete volume(Disk)?

Comment: there is support but you need to use the placeOrder method for that as the example that I posted

Comment: when you said Do we have similar kind of RestApiClient service to Create/delete the additional volume? I thought you mean to add more disks to the VM is that right?